# Container Class in Javascript

Tags: javascript, oop

Total OOP beginner and doing all this in Javascript, so forgive any blatant dumbness on my part:

I want to keep track of dynamically created objects. I believe my solution to this problem is to use a container class.

1. Is a container class what I want?
2. If yes, is my implementation correct?

---

**Branch** objects are dynamically generated.

**Branches** objects contain a *Branch* objects array.

```
function Branches() {

    function Branch() {
        var _id;

        _id = Math.round(Math.random()*10);

        this.getId = function() {
            return _id;
        }

    }

    this.createBranch = function() {
        var branch = new Branch;
        _branches.push(branch);
    }

    this.getBranches = function() {
        return _branches;
    }

    this.getBranchIds = function() {
        var branch_list = this.getBranches();

        var branch_ids = [];

        for (var i = 0; i < branch_list.length; i++) {
            var branch_id = branch_list[i].getId();
            branch_ids.push(branch_id);
        }

        return branch_ids;
    }

    var _branches = [];

}

// code test
var test = new Branches;

for (var i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
    test.createBranch();
}

console.log("Branch IDs:\n" + test.getBranchIds());
```

Comment: Both questions seems to me not in the right format for StackOverflow, the first one asks for an opinion, the second one asks for a code review.

Comment: I don't know JS but **if your code is currently working as intended** please feel free to post it in CodeReview.Stackexchange.com

Comment: @andrea-casaccia Sorry about posting in the wrong section.

Comment: @Zak Thanks for linking me to the right section.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code works (yay!) despite a few simple problems (you're not generating unique IDs for each branch, for example). If you are happy with the design you chose, feel free to take the code to [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/). There you will get tips for improving the code as it currently is.

To answer your first, more conceptual question, what you've written is definitely one way to implement what you want. You've gone with a *Factory* pattern here. You've written a class, `Branches`, that provides an interface for creating objects of the class `Branch`.

`createBranch` is known as a Factory method; it handles the creation of the new object, and in your case, keeping track of that object in your array. It also returns the new object so the user can interact with the `Branch` object as necessary.

One thing to consider about your implementation is that `Branch` is private, visible only to code inside the `Branches` class. This has a few implications that come to mind:

1. the only way to create a `Branch` object is through the `createBranch` factory

   - all `Branch` objects will be tracked because of this
2. Any properties of the `Branch` constructor (meaning, anything like `Branch.property = value`) will not be immediately accessible outside of the `Branches` class.

This may be what you want. But if there is no reason to hide the `Branch` constructor or prototype from plain sight, then I'd suggest other design patterns.

A good strategy might be to use those constructor properties. This way, you reduce your code by a lot, and have one fewer class to deal with (but no factory methods):

```
function Branch() {
    var _id = Math.round(Math.random() * 10);

    this.getId = function () {
        return _id;
    };

    Branch.branches.push(this);
}

Branch.branches = [];
Branch.getIds = function () {
    var ids = [];
    for (var i in Branch.branches)
        ids.push(Branch.branches[i].getId());
    return ids;
};

// test code
for (var i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
    new Branch();
}

console.log("Branch IDs:\n" + Branch.getIds());
```

Comment: Oh wow that's very clever and compact! OOP thinking is so wildly different from what I'm used to, I have a ton to learn about its design patterns. Thank you for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: No problem! OOP is intimidating at first but it will soon become a way of life. :)